# Assigning per-thread objects to task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

What's the practice of assigning must-be-unique-per-thread 3rd party objects to be used with in a task? (I need to ensure that when the tasks are really parallel-ing, they each obtain a different, and, expensive to recreate and thus reused objects.)

Should I pre-init the objects according to the number of max degree of parallelism into some concurrent collection, and make the task "borrow" the object at the begin, then "return" the object at the end? Should I do it with ThreadLocal? What's the best contention free way?

Thanks

Edit: I found that what I was looking for is roughly the "localInit" func argument of the Parallel For calls

Answer (score 2):

> Assigning per-thread objects to task?
>
> What's the practice of assigning must-be-unique-per-thread 3rd party objects to be used with in a task?

There is no concept in .NET as *"per-thread"* objects, this isn't COM.  .NET objects have no *thread-marshalling* unlike COM.

> Should I pre-init the objects according to the number of max degree of parallelism into some concurrent collection

No, that's expensive. Generally you just allocate your objects and pass them to say `Parallel.ForEach` (or PLINQ's `ForAll`) and let it work out the number of threads whilst enumerating your collection.  TPL is rather smart when it comes to thread allocation.

> What's the best contention free way?

Well one way is to avoid putting explicit locks on your objects and instead design your code to somewhat stateless that returns some value during a function call that can either be used in a PLINQ statement or added to say a `ConcurrentBag` during execution of `Parallel.ForEach`.

### Tell me more

- [Introduction to PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq)

Comment: To clarify, I need to ensure that when the tasks are really parallel-ing, they each obtain a different, and, expensive to recreate and thus reused objects.

Comment: Tasks are tasks, objects are objects, that's two different things.  You're still thinking _old school_.  You don't thread-local for the most part in .NET.  `Task`;  `Parallel.ForEach` and PLINQ's `ForAll` take care of that for you.

Comment: I am talking about methods of some other objects that are called in the tasks though

Comment: I found that what I was looking for is roughly the "localInit" func argument of the Parallel For calls.